# Python: OpenCV - Selecting Region of an Image

Tags: python, opencv

I want to select the region where the Data Matrix is placed.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\MyAccount\\Desktop\\datamatrix.png')
dmc = img1[300:588, 1225:1512]
plt.imshow(dmc)
plt.show()
```

I only receive a slim white area, but not a single region of this matrix.
The ROI-Formular is [y:y+h, x:x+w], but it is not working.

The image has the size 1240 x 626.

The matrix has the attributes:
left=938, top=323, width=287, height=288.

[image]

Comment: Are the dimension you have given correct? You said the image has resolution 1240 by 626, but you're trying to access 1225:1512.

Comment: The ROI is really confusing. You start with the y-coordinates and then the x-coordinates. In this expample https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html in section "Image Roi" I didn't understand the x-coordinates.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm the `y` coordinate initialization was wrong. check out the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the ROI-Formular which is `[y:y+h, x:x+w]`, however the initial point on `y` coordinate is wrong that is why you are cropping the white region of the image.

You are probably looking for:

```
dmc = im[13:13+287, 938:938+287]
cv2.imshow('dmc', dmc)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates you specify in your code don't correspond to what you describe.

Change them to:

```
dmc = img1[323:611, 938:1225]
```

Comment: Sorry, I only receive an empty (white) image. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you like to have a relative formula:

```
import cv2

left=938
top=323
width=287
height=288

img = cv2.imread('temp.png', 0)
imgh, imgw = img.shape[:2]
# compute starting position of top
img = img[(imgh/2-height)/2:(imgh/2-height)/2+height, left:left+width]
cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Result Image]